# Serde/jsonrpc-core: convert between to representations of the same data

Tags: rust, json-rpc, serde

I utilize the `jsonrpc-core` library to for communication based on the JSON-RPC 2.0 specifications. When registering rpc methods via `add_method`, they take one parameter, which is an already parsed `jsonrpc_core::Params` value that represents the params of the request object.

However, I have an  enum data type that is also a representation of this data:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum Event {
    Warning { level: String, time: String, source: String, log: String },
}
```

I can now easily convert between those representations through

```
let params: jsonrpc_core::Params = ...
let string: String = serde_json::to_string(&params).unwrap();

let event: Event = serde_json::from_str(&string).unwrap();
```

However, serializing and deserializing in this manner seems like a waste, is there any other way to convert from two equivalent types that implement `serde_json`'s `Serialize`/`Deserialize` traits?